# How do I fetch just the ids via ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
class PersonAddress < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

I would like to fetch only the PersonAddress ids (primary keys) using a ActiveRecord query, how should I do that, something similar to `PersonAddress.find_all_by_person_id(person.id)` which returns a set of address ids alone. (e.g. if the person has 3 addresses, then it should return 3 ids and not PersonAddress objects)

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is using :select parameter:

```
PersonAddress.find_all_by_person_id(person.id, :select => :id).map(&:id)
=> [2, 3, 5]  # Fake ids
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on which Rails version you are using... but this might work:

```
PersonAddress.find_all_by_person_id(person.id).select("id")
```